# Is it necessary to pass value to an array before writing to EEPROM?

Tags: c, embedded

I am new to embedded world and would like to know if passing value to an array before writing to EEPROM do any good for reliability or accuracy? I am using I2C protocol here. Below is the difference of writing a value to my EEPROM chip. I see mostly people store data into an array before writing.  if neither for reliability nor accuracy, what is the reason behind it?

```
uint64_t OperationTime;
uint8_t e2prom_w_buf[256];
uint8_t i;
for(i =0 ; i < 8 ; i++ )
{
    e2prom_w_buf[i]=OperationTime >> i*8;
}
e2prom_PageWrite(&e2prom_w_buf, Address, 8);
```

&

```
uint8_t
for(i =0 ; i < 8 ; i++ )
{
e2prom_PageWrite((OperationTime << i*8), Address, 8); // do I need a uint8_t cast here for OperationTime?
}
```

The OperationTime keeps incrementing in timer interrupt function per second

**I2C setup 100kHz**

Comment: What does `e2prom_PageWrite`? What arguments do `e2prom_PageWrite` expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing an EEPROM in in a block is faster than multiple single byte operations.  You should look at the data sheet for the specific EEPROM to understand why, but just to pick a typical SPI<sup>see note EEPROM as an example (AT25M01 in this case).  It has a byte write sequence thus:</sup>

<sub>Note: I chose an SPI part for illustration because the timing diagrams are a little simpler.  I note you mention I2C - the principle is the same, the bus transactions are more complicated.</sub>

[image]

<sup>©2019 Microchip Technology Inc.</sup>

and a *Page Write* thus:

[image]

<sup>©2019 Microchip Technology Inc.</sup>

The Page Write can write up to 256 bytes in a burst with only the start address, while for a byte write you have to write the address of every byte, and have to wait for the write to complete (busy state) before you can write the next one.  So you have to send 5 bytes for a single byte write, but only 4 + n bytes for a page write.  So in terms of SPI (or I2C in your case)) bus activity, writing single bytes requires nearly 4 times the number of bytes to be written to the bus.

Also in the case of the AT25M01 in this example, the write cycle time is "up-to 5ms".  That is 5ms for one Byte Write or 5ms for a Page Write.  So for byte writes the 8 bytes in your example may take as much as 40ms, whereas for a Page Write it will take no more than 5ms.

Another benefit of page writes is that on many MCU's you can send the data using DMA (Direct Memory Access) so that there is little or no software overhead is writing to the EEPROM, and the MCU can do other work.

Comment: Thank you for the explicit explanation. I am using ATMEL AT24C02. It also has the same max. write cycle time of 5ms as AT25M01 .  I wonder if there is any read cycle time and limitation for reading bytes in most EEPROM. I know writing data to EEPROM could cause wear and tear. what about read operation?

Comment: For read access the bus speed is the limiting factor.  In that case SPI is capable of faster reads, but typical EEPROM sizes generally make that largely irrelevant.  In most cases you read what you want from an EEPROM into RAM at start-up and then your done.

Answer (score 0):

Memory of some EEPROM devices are organized in pages, which consists of multiple bytes. Writing multiple bytes into the same page takes the same time as writing a single byte. So, a page write operation is preferred for faster writes/programming.